# Squared triangular number

Tags: discrete-mathematics, quadratics

Say I have `n=5` I would like to perform the following equation:

`5^2 + 4^2 + 3^2 + 2^2 + 1^2 = 55`

I know that a triangular number can be worked out with the following equation:

`(n(n+1)/2)`

However it is at this point where I've not been able to work out the required adjustments to suite this use case.

What would be the correct equation?

Comment: $$\sum_{i=1}^n i^{2}$$

Comment: Hint: it's a cubic.

Comment: https://oeis.org/A000330

Comment: The general case is known as [Faulhaber's formula](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faulhaber%27s_formula)

Comment: @RossMillikan thanks for the info!

Comment: @rogerl I've worked out the functions up to $$\sum_{x=1}^n x^{31}$$ using matrices that are a variation of Pascal's triangle as shown in your link. I need to dig out my papers and write it up for publication.

Comment: You should first read the article on Faulhaber's formula linked to above. Nice job working out the cases, but you should be aware that it's been done before :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$\sum_{k=1}^n k^2 = \frac{1}{6}n(n+1)(2n+1)$$
with n=5 :$$\frac{1}{6}*5*6*11=55$$
it is sometimes called number for quadratic pyramid.
trula